# Абстрактный класс, модификаторы доступа

Tags: java, ооп

Есть абстрактный класс, в нем реализовано два метода - один `public`, другой `protected`. Вот задумался, что за смысл использовать модификатор доступа `public` для метода, если извне доступа все-равно нету, т.к. инстанциировать абстрактный класс нельзя?

Comment: Для того, чтобы другие классы имели доступ к этому методу у экземпляров класса-наследника

Answer (score 2):

Сделано для соблюдения инкапсуляции и полиморфизма также и в классах наследниках.

Допустим есть класс:

```java
abstract class Human {

    protected String name;
    private String surname;

    public Human(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.friends = new ArrayList<Human>();
    }

    public String greet() {
        return "Hello, " + getFullName();
    }

    private String getFullName() {
        return name + "_" + surname;
    }

    // abstract private void setName();  // Нет смысла. `private` не переопределишь в дочерних классах

    public void addFriend(Human human) {
        friends.add(human);
    }

    public ArrayList<Human> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

}
```

Неважно, переопределим ли мы метод `greet` в дочерних классах или нет, в экземплярах дочерних классов мы сможем к нему обращаться, как и к полю `name`. А доступ к методу `getFullName` так же как и к полю `surname` в дочерних классах будет закрыт, так как их модификатор сохранится как `private`.

В классе определен метод `addFriend`, принимающий объект `Human` - то есть самого `Human` и его дочерние классы

Создадим подкласс `Human`:

```java
class Man extends Human {

    public Man(String name, String surname) {
        super(name, surname);
    }

    // При переопределении метод остаётся `public`
    @Override
    public String greet() {
        return super.greet() + "\nHow are you?";
    }

}
```

Этот класс также является `Human`, наследуясь от него и реализуя тем самым контракт этого класса

Теперь можем посмотреть результат применения модификаторов в абстрактном классе:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Инкапсуляция
    Man man = new Man("Edgar", "Nollan");
    System.out.println(man.name);           // Edgar
    System.out.println(man.surname);        // error: surname has private access in Human
    System.out.println(man.greet());        // Hello, Edgar_Nollan\nHow are you?
    System.out.println(man.getFullName());  // error: getFullName() has private access in Man
    // Полиморфизм
    Man friend = new Man("Brad", "Pitt");  // `Man` является подклассом `Human`. Мы можем передавать его в методы как объект `Human`
    man.addFriend(friend);
    System.out.println(man.getFriends().get(0).name);
}
```

По сути, со стороны полиморфизма конкретные модификаторы роли не играют. Они просто сохраняются теми же, которыми были определены в абстрактном классе, сохраняя тем самым контракт, определённый этим абстрактным классом

Answer (score 1):

Публичные методы абстрактного класса декларируют интерфейс данной структуры наследования.

При этом данный публичный метод абстрактного класса может быть также задекларирован как абстрактный - т.е. не содержать в себе вообще никакой реализации, а только объявлять формат вызова данной функциональности.

Таким образом, наследники данного абстрактного класса могут сделать свою реализацию этого публичного метода.

Этот публичный метод может быть вызван как для переменных типа наследников, так и для переменных с типом базового **абстрактного** класса. В отличии от объектов, которые нельзя создать с типом абстрактного класса, объявить переменную данного типа **можно**.

В объявленную переменную типа абстрактного класса можно поместить ссылку на любой объект из иерархии наследования данного абстрактного класса. Т.е. любого наследника. В зависимости от того, какой объект будет помещен в данную переменную, при вызове публичного метода будет выполняться та функциональность, которая определена в классе-наследнике. Если этот публичный метод в классе-наследнике **не** перекрыт, то будет выполняться функциональность базового класса.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум для применения полиморфизма. Публичный метод реализации этого абстрактного класса может быть вызван по ссылке абстрактного типа на эту реализацию.

Впрочем, никто не мешает вызвать переопределенный публичный метод по ссылке типа реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу просто, кратко и понятно:

1. Модификатор доступа сохраняется при наследовании, и к реализации метода будет доступ из любой точки программы, если метод в абстрактном класссе объявлен как `public`.
   Вот пример:

```
public abstract class A {

  public abstract void doSomething();

}
```

```
public class B {
  
  //К этой реализации будет доступ из любой точки программы!
  @Override
  public void doSomething(){ 
     //Реализация
  }

}
```

2. В теории, метод в абстрактном классе может иметь реализацию и быть объявлен как `public static`:

```
public abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
  
  //абстрактные и не абстрактные методы класса...

  public static void doSomething(){
    //Какая- то реализация
  }

}
```

И чтобы обратиться к этому методу, достаточно указать имя класса:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(Sring[]args){
     SomeAbstractClass.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Такое не особо часто встречается, но в теории тоже может быть.